# I am getting an error 'T must be a data set formatted by fmt.', while using machine learning function

Tags: matlab, machine-learning

I am getting an error message every time I try to use any functions from the ML toolbox, I am using MATLAB 2017 over Linux platform.

```
load fisheriris
t = fitctree(meas,species,'PredictorNames',{'SL' 'SW' 'PL' 'PW'})
```

```
Error using categorical/unique (line 58)
T must be a data set formatted by fmt.
```

Comment: Your data is likely incorrectly formatted.

Comment: @LukaszTracewski: Thank you for your response. The problem is not with the data because the same lines of code works in windows but Ubuntu. I am using the code:                                                                                             load ionosphere
tc = fitctree(X,Y)